# Jest encountered an unexpected token in React (error by personal npm library)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I made a test code (just render and console)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { CheckExperienceHistory } from './CheckExperienceHistory';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

it('name validation', async () => {
    beforeAll(() => console.log('--- start test ---'));
    render(<CheckExperienceHistory />);
})
```

then, I got error when npm run test

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /Users/stefancho/WebstormProjects/my-project/node_modules/wink_commons/dist/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import * as API from './api';
                                                                                                    ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token *

      12 | import Alert from 'antd/lib/alert';
      13 |
    > 14 | import { Download } from 'some-library';
         | ^
      15 |
      16 | import {action} from '../../../redux/actions/index';
      17 | import {api, service} from '../../configs/';

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/javascript/members/components/member/CheckExperienceHistory.js:14:1)
```

so I added tranformIgnorePatterns to package.json, but it didn't work (same error)

```json
// package.json
  "jest": {
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(some-library)/)",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ],
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  }
```

I think, jest attempt to parse `some-library` (this is personal library) but it failed to compile it, and I'm wondering why transformIgnorePatterns is not work.